# how to display json data got from json2 format

Tags: json

I get json data from Struts Action, like below:
I want to precoss this data in JSP page, but I tried to use .$each or attr, all does not woek, I use Json2.js  JSON.stringfy() get these data, so how I can fet each key and value in it?

[{"agreementNumber":"161446628","employeeIndicator":"N","enrollmentSrc":"363","fepIndicator":"N","groupCancelDate":null,"groupCancelDateTime":0,"groupCnlDate":"","groupEffDate":"20070701","groupEffectiveDate":{"date":1,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":1183262400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":107},"groupEffectiveDateTime":1183262400000,"groupName":"Westminster College","groupNumber":"01501701 ","index":"1","memberList":{"enrollmetSrc":"363","groupNumber":"01501701 ","memberList":[{"agreementNumber":"161446628","birthDate":{"date":10,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":1,"seconds":0,"time":-217450800000,"timezoneOffset":300,"year":63},"birthDateTime":-217450800000,"cancelDate":null,"cancelDateTime":0,"classCode":" I3","effectiveDate":{"date":1,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":1183262400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":107},"effectiveDateTime":1183262400000,"firstName":"KENNETH ","gender":"M","groupName":"","groupNumber":"01501701 ","lastName":"ROMIG ","medicareAdvantage":"","memberId":375315,"middleName":"J ","pin":"1","preTtlName":" ","relation":"Self","relationCode":"1","sucTtlName":" "},{"agreementNumber":"161446628","birthDate":{"date":23,"day":5,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":7,"seconds":0,"time":-200692800000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":63},"birthDateTime":-200692800000,"cancelDate":null,"cancelDateTime":0,"classCode":" I3","effectiveDate":{"date":1,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":1183262400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":107},"effectiveDateTime":1183262400000,"firstName":"KIMBERLY ","gender":"F","groupName":"","groupNumber":"01501701 ","lastName":"ROMIG ","medicareAdvantage":"","memberId":1424959,"middleName":"G ","pin":"3","preTtlName":" ","relation":"Spouse","relationCode":"2","sucTtlName":" "},{"agreementNumber":"161446628","birthDate":{"date":8,"day":1,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":0,"seconds":0,"time":631774800000,"timezoneOffset":300,"year":90},"birthDateTime":631774800000,"cancelDate":null,"cancelDateTime":0,"classCode":" I3","effectiveDate":{"date":1,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":1183262400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":107},"effectiveDateTime":1183262400000,"firstName":"NICOLE ","gender":"F","groupName":"","groupNumber":"01501701 ","lastName":"CRUMBACHER ","medicareAdvantage":"","memberId":375314,"middleName":"A ","pin":"4","preTtlName":" ","relation":"Child","relationCode":"3","sucTtlName":" "},{"agreementNumber":"161446628","birthDate":{"date":7,"day":6,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":994478400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":101},"birthDateTime":994478400000,"cancelDate":null,"cancelDateTime":0,"classCode":" I3","effectiveDate":{"date":1,"day":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":6,"seconds":0,"time":1183262400000,"timezoneOffset":240,"year":107},"effectiveDateTime":1183262400000,"firstName":"NATHAN ","gender":"M","groupName":"","groupNumber":"01501701 ","lastName":"ROMIG ","medicareAdvantage":"","memberId":1424960,"middleName":"J ","pin":"6","preTtlName":" ","relation":"Child","relationCode":"3","sucTtlName":" "}]},"ownerCode":"HM"}]

Answer (score 0):

Your json object has a complex structure so I am not going to write the function how to map it properly but I am going to give you some tools how to understand it better and work with it.

To see your json object more clearly use a an online json pareser http://json.parser.online.fr/ just paste your json object there and in the right you will see the tree like structure.

Here you can see examples how to access you json object properties [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamikus/tk9N2/)
I know that this is not what you want exactly but will help you build it.

Comment: Thxs a lot for  ur example and tools! it can make clear my json structure, but my problem is that I don't  knwo why when I put alert(test[0].agreementNumber); it does not work, or show undefined

Comment: could you write how you handle the json object? usually you should do like this:
success:function(data){
alert(data[0].agreementNumber);
}

Comment: test is the variable name where I point to my json object yours maybe differnt that is why you get undefined

Comment: I got it, I process json object,and stringfy again, that is the issues